# A 13-letter word

Tags: word, wordplay

Use these clues to find the 13-letter word:

> 9, 10, 8, 5, 2 - Made from Bell.
>    10, 3, 4, 9, 6 - Big animal with a long name.
>    12, 13, 6, 5, 2, 1 - Very high.
>    7, 10, 8, 13 - Could relate to photos or guns.
>    11, 1, 3, 6, 13 - A protagonist of Dostoyevsky.

---

**What is the 13-letter word?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Deipnosophist

Reasoning:

Very high

> STONED

Could relate to photos or guns

> SHOT

A protagonist of Dostoyevsky

> IDIOT (from "The Idiot")

Retrofitting the two other clues:

Made from Bell

> PHONE

Big animal with long name

> HIPPO (Short for hippopotamus)

Comment: Add the other two clues and your answer will be complete. :)

Comment: The animal is hippo

Comment: And apparently [BELL](http://www.bell.ca/) is a canadian company manufacturing phones.

Comment: @Ankoganit I see. Didn't know that - I was thinking Alexander Graham Bell, and fiddling with bell metal before that.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Alexander Graham Bell is correct - he is the inventor after all, so he made it.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but that would be "made BY bell", right?

Comment: @Ankoganit but that would discard the double meaning.